# Center horizontal list (li) element on multiple lines

Tags: html, alignment, html-lists

I have a list of item that must be cetered as a text, but if the line is not fully fill those element are place at the very left of the last ligne.

Ex:

```
item1 item2 item3
item4 item5
```

What I whanted is more something like

```
item1 item2 item3
   item4  item5
```

Comment: Just a side note, you should not try to center bulleted list items, as you will run into cross-browser issues. If you absolutely need bullets, first remove them with `list-style:none;` then create a bullet image and display it using `background-image`

Comment: Actually I don't need to have any bullet. I use list element (li) beacuse by the sementhic the item is an item in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set their CSS property

```
display: inline;
```

and their container

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: This does not work, beacuse the li need to be float left to stand side by side.

Comment: You don't actually need `float:left` to make them "stand side by side." `display:inline` will accomplish that for you.

Comment: Sorry guys, This work now. the center probleme was from a div inside the li that was not display:inline. I change im for a span and now it work as a charm!